# How can I copy all the data from certain colored cells in a Google Spreadsheet to a single cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I've only just started using a spreadsheet and I'm wondering how to take all the data from cells of a certain color, then place that data in a single cell?

Answer (score 1):

If by saying *take all the data* you mean using an aggregate function like **sum** or **average** or something similar, then you should use scripting functionality that Google Spreadsheet provides.

Please see the answer for similar question [Sum data based on cell color in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19467/sum-data-based-on-cell-color-in-google-spreadsheets)

If you want to concatenate data from certain cells and copy the result to a specific cell, again you should use a script similar to one that is used to sum data based on cell color.