# How to auto-update function based on background color

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've been referencing [@w0lf's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19467/sum-data-based-on-cell-color-in-google-spreadsheets) to help me calculate the sum of cells based on their background color in Google Sheets. From the comments and some other research it appears that changing the color doesn't trigger a change in the cell. This causes my function to never update.

Does anyone know a way to force my sum function to update when just the background color of a cell in my range changes? I've tried changing the update settings under "spreadsheet settings" already, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Sum data based on cell color in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19467/sum-data-based-on-cell-color-in-google-spreadsheets#comment72151_25847) by [Jeff Lockhart](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/46608/jeff-lockhart)

> @aezell In order to have the sumWhereForegroundColorIs() equation
>   update when the cells in its range change, append the cells within the
>   2nd argument string as a 3rd argument range like so:
>   sumWhereForegroundColorIs(getForegroundColor("B3"), "E3:AL3", E3:AL3).
>   Unfortunately if you need the equation to update when the foreground
>   color of any of the cells in that range change, this is not possible.
>   The cell does not fire a changed event when the color changes, only
>   when the content does.

So, you have to change the content in order to make the referred custom function to be recalculated.

Comment: Thanks, I find it odd that a color change wouldn't trigger a change event in the cell? I'm trying to find actual google documentation on this to see if there is a way to capture the color change and update my function. Until then I'll accept Jeff's knowledge as truth.

Comment: @Braden: Usually there isn't "actual google documentation" for non-included features. They usually document only features that are included. For the documented stuff, see [Spreadsheet Service - Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)